# Meta Programmers not listed under my Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: support, status-bydesign

When I go to my user page at stackexchange.com, it says I have 16 accounts, but does not list Meta Programmers. I know all Meta sites share the reputation with their main site, except SO, but considering the badges are NOT shared, why doesn't it show up as a separate account?

It makes it hard for people to see if I am active in Metas other than SO's and from my perspective, its misleading. If the Stack Exchange site is only going to show my Programmers account, then it needs to show my Meta Programmers' badges as well.

Comment: I've removed the discussion tag, however if you edit the question to be a feature request instead of a discussion or a support request, flag it for moderation attention so I can remove the [status-bydesing] and ask the community team to join in.

Comment: Related feature request: [Can we add Meta badges to flair?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/can-we-add-meta-badges-to-flair)

Answer (score 5):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), Meta Stack Overflow is the only Meta listed in the network profile, and that's because it's a bit special. Per site Metas are considered an extension of the main site, and your per site Meta accounts an extension of your site account.

I don't know how useful it would be to list per site Metas in the network profile, your Meta participation is interesting only to the specific community, and your Meta account is linked to from your [main account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/37315/austin-henley).